# Swift Firebase observe single event only looking at first child

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

So I have some code that I am trying to use to display all children of a child of the main Firebase project but my code is only displaying the first child and nothing else. I've looked around and could find a solution.
Here is a picture of the Firebase Realtime Database structure:

[image: Image of database]

Here is the Json code of the entire database:

```
{
  "bulletin" : {
    "athletics" : [ {
      "ID" : 6777,
      "articleAuthor" : "First Last",
      "articleBody" : "This is the body of the article in district.",
      "articleDate" : 1230,
      "articleImages" : [ "https://i.imgur.com/2yQLNul.jpeg", "https://i.imgur.com/o62ZXjg.png" ],
      "articleTitle" : "TestTitlesdd"
    } ],
    "colleges" : [ {
      "ID" : 9999,
      "articleAuthor" : "First Last",
      "articleBody" : "This is the body of the article in asb.",
      "articleDate" : 1230,
      "articleImages" : [ "https://i.imgur.com/2yQLNul.jpeg", "https://i.imgur.com/o62ZXjg.png" ],
      "articleTitle" : "TestTitlessda"
    } ],
    "events" : [ {
      "ID" : 567567,
      "articleAuthor" : "First Last",
      "articleBody" : "This is the body of the article in sports.",
      "articleDate" : 1230,
      "articleImages" : [ "https://i.imgur.com/2yQLNul.jpeg", "https://i.imgur.com/o62ZXjg.png" ],
      "articleTitle" : "TestTitlesaa"
    } ],
    "others" : [ {
      "ID" : 6666,
      "articleAuthor" : "First Last",
      "articleBody" : "This is the body of the article in district.",
      "articleDate" : 1230,
      "articleImages" : [ "https://i.imgur.com/2yQLNul.jpeg", "https://i.imgur.com/o62ZXjg.png" ],
      "articleTitle" : "TestTitlesdd"
    } ],
    "reference" : [ {
      "ID" : 3345,
      "articleAuthor" : "First Last",
      "articleBody" : "This is the body of the article in district.",
      "articleDate" : 1230,
      "articleImages" : [ "https://i.imgur.com/2yQLNul.jpeg", "https://i.imgur.com/o62ZXjg.png" ],
      "articleTitle" : "TestTitlesdd"
    } ],
    "seniors" : [ {
      "ID" : 333,
      "articleAuthor" : "First Last",
      "articleBody" : "This is the body of the article.",
      "articleDate" : 1230,
      "articleImages" : [ "https://i.imgur.com/2yQLNul.jpeg", "https://i.imgur.com/o62ZXjg.png" ],
      "articleTitle" : "TestTitle1"
    } ]
  },
  "homepage" : {
    "213" : {
      "ID" : 213,
      "articleAuthor" : "First Last",
      "articleBody" : "This is the body of the article in district.",
      "articleDate" : 1230,
      "articleImages" : [ "https://i.imgur.com/2yQLNul.jpeg", "https://i.imgur.com/o62ZXjg.png" ],
      "articleTitle" : "dis2"
    },
    "321" : {
      "ID" : 321,
      "articleAuthor" : "First Last",
      "articleBody" : "This is the body of the article in disrict.",
      "articleDate" : 1230,
      "articleImages" : [ "https://i.imgur.com/2yQLNul.jpeg", "https://i.imgur.com/o62ZXjg.png" ],
      "articleTitle" : "district"
    },
    "999" : {
      "ID" : 999,
      "articleAuthor" : "First Last",
      "articleBody" : "This is the body of the article in sports.",
      "articleDate" : 1230,
      "articleImages" : [ "https://i.imgur.com/2yQLNul.jpeg", "https://i.imgur.com/o62ZXjg.png" ],
      "articleTitle" : "S2"
    },
    "2322" : {
      "ID" : 2322,
      "articleAuthor" : "First Last",
      "articleBody" : "This is the body of the article in sports.",
      "articleDate" : 1230,
      "articleImages" : [ "https://i.imgur.com/2yQLNul.jpeg", "https://i.imgur.com/o62ZXjg.png" ],
      "articleTitle" : "S"
    },
    "4134" : {
      "ID" : 4134,
      "articleAuthor" : "First Last",
      "articleBody" : "This is the body of the article in asb.",
      "articleDate" : 1230,
      "articleImages" : [ "https://i.imgur.com/2yQLNul.jpeg", "https://i.imgur.com/o62ZXjg.png" ],
      "articleTitle" : "ASB"
    },
    "12331" : {
      "ID" : 12331,
      "articleAuthor" : "First Last",
      "articleBody" : "This is the body of the article in featured.",
      "articleDate" : 1230,
      "articleImages" : [ "https://i.imgur.com/2yQLNul.jpeg", "https://i.imgur.com/o62ZXjg.png" ],
      "articleTitle" : "F2"
    },
    "41435" : {
      "ID" : 41435,
      "articleAuthor" : "First Last",
      "articleBody" : "This is the body of the article in asb.",
      "articleDate" : 1230,
      "articleImages" : [ "https://i.imgur.com/2yQLNul.jpeg", "https://i.imgur.com/o62ZXjg.png" ],
      "articleTitle" : "ASB2"
    },
    "325431" : {
      "ID" : 325431,
      "articleAuthor" : "First Last",
      "articleBody" : "This is the body of the article in featured.",
      "articleDate" : 1230,
      "articleImages" : [ "https://i.imgur.com/2yQLNul.jpeg", "https://i.imgur.com/o62ZXjg.png" ],
      "articleTitle" : "F"
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the code I'm using to access it in my Swift project:

```
ref.child("homepage").observeSingleEvent(of: .childAdded) { (snapshot) in
    print(snapshot.childrenCount)
    let enumerator = snapshot.children;
    while let rest = enumerator.nextObject() as? DataSnapshot{
            print(rest);
});
```

Here is the output of above program:

```
6
Snap (ID) 213
Snap (articleAuthor) First Last
Snap (articleBody) This is the body of the article in district.
Snap (articleDate) 1230
Snap (articleImages) {
    0 = "https://i.imgur.com/2yQLNul.jpeg";
    1 = "https://i.imgur.com/o62ZXjg.png";
}
Snap (articleTitle) dis2
```

As you can see, it only prints 6 for the children count even though I have  8 articles so I suspect it's outputting the number of children for **EACH** article. It's also only outputting the data for only the first article which is something I don't want it to do.

I've also tried encapsulating articles into sections but it always seems to skip every other article and only display the first article. In addition, if I remove `ref.child("homepage")` it doesn't display anything at all which I assume is because it doesn't have anything to refer to. I would all the articles displayed. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.value` instead of `.childAdded`.. `.Value` retrieves all the data each time its called while `.ChildAdded` looks for changes in the children of the reference

```
ref.child("homepage").observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
    print(snapshot.childrenCount)
    let enumerator = snapshot.children;
    while let rest = enumerator.nextObject() as? DataSnapshot{
            print(rest);
});
```

Comment: Nice, I didn't realize this was the issue. I also just found out that you can use .observe(.childAdded) and it would work but this is more of what I'm looking for. Thanks.